# replace content after do a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to replace all possible results equal '0' to NULL value.
What's the best option? Use a case statement or replace command in this case:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(IF(stat='open',1, NULL)) 'open',
       COUNT(IF(stat='close',1, NULL)) 'close',
       COUNT(IF(stat='all',1, NULL)) 'all',
       COUNT(IF(stat='reopen',1, NULL)) 'reopen',
       COUNT(IF(stat='finish',1, NULL)) 'finish'
FROM dashboard group by name order by name = 'Party' desc

+----------+------+-------+-----+--------+--------+
| name     | open | close | all | reopen | finish |
+----------+------+-------+-----+--------+--------+
| Party    |   21 |     0 |   0 |      0 |      0 |
+----------+------+-------+-----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Your query makes no reference to equalling 0. What are you trying to do? Where is this going in your query?

Comment: like to change '0' to NULL result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`NULLIF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) function.

```
SELECT name, 
       NULLIF(COUNT(IF(stat='open',1, NULL)), 0) 'open',
       NULLIF(COUNT(IF(stat='close',1, NULL)), 0) 'close',
       NULLIF(COUNT(IF(stat='all',1, NULL)), 0) 'all',
       NULLIF(COUNT(IF(stat='reopen',1, NULL)), 0) 'reopen',
       NULLIF(COUNT(IF(stat='finish',1, NULL)), 0) 'finish'
FROM dashboard 
group by name 
order by name = 'Party' desc
```

`NULLIF()` returns the first value unless it's equal to the second value, then it returns `NULL`.

BTW, you can simplify `COUNT(IF(stat='xxx', 1, NULL))` to `SUM(stat='xxx')`.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT name,
       NULLIF(SUM(stat = 'open'), 0) as open,
       NULLIF(SUM(stat = 'close'), 0) as close,
       NULLIF(SUM(stat = 'all'), 0) as all,
       NULLIF(SUM(stat = 'reopen'), 0) as reopen,
       NULLIF(SUM(stat = 'finish'), 0) as finish
FROM dashboard 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY name = 'Party' desc;
```

Another uses `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN stat = 'open' THEN 1 END) as open,
       . . .
```